Using rebasing when working with a vendor branch
I'm trying to set up a system where we can have a vendor branch that receives regular updates and we don't touch the codebase of. Instead, we have another branch running side-by-side with the vendor branch that we add custom code to for our needs.
The obvious solution is to just merge vendor into our branch each time vendor receives an update, but I'm worried about merge conflicts compounding over time and growing more complicated with each merge. The method I'm trying is rebasing the main branch onto the tip of vendor each time vendor is updated, and resolving conflicts on a per-commit basis just to make sure things are clear. The problem is of course the fact that it's rebasing a public branch. With enough communication do you think it will be fine to rebase and force push to main after vendor is updated, or should that be avoided entirely since it will make it difficult to have any other changes on other machines where you're needing to force-pull the main branch?
